# Android phone reset but leaking memory

Tags: android, debugging, memory-leaks

Looking at the Dalvik debugger for an Android app I'm writing, I noticed that there's a set of notifications that keep repeating, with an increasing Frank handle count each time.  I presumed that my app had a memory leak, and when deleting my app didn't fix it I reset the phone (HTC Tattoo, running 1.6).  However, attaching the debugger to the completely clean phone (i.e. before installing my app) I'm still seeing the same repeated notification with the Frank handle count continuing to increase.

Anyone have any idea what's going on; is this a red herring?

Ta,
Owen

Here's the repeated bit of the log file (apologies, but I can't figure out how to get this to format sensibly - let me know and I'll reformat it properly):

```
07-23 16:40:58.209: INFO/LogService(590): 2011-07-23    16:40:58    127.0.0.1    -    127.0.0.1    8182    GET    /info/    -    200    911    0    52    http://null    -    -
07-23 16:40:58.209: INFO/Server(590): Addition of the standard header "pragma" is discouraged as a future versions of the Restlet API will directly support it.
07-23 16:40:58.219: WARN/Server(590): Addition of the standard header "cache-control" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
07-23 16:40:58.219: WARN/Server(590): Addition of the standard header "expires" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
07-23 16:40:58.339: INFO/global(590): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
07-23 16:40:58.339: INFO/global(590): Default buffer size used in BufferedOutputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
07-23 16:40:58.349: INFO/LogFilter(590): Couldn't find the mandatory "Host" HTTP header.
07-23 16:40:58.369: DEBUG/Frank Liu(590): enter FDInfo-handle
07-23 16:40:58.369: DEBUG/Frank Liu(590): Frank handle count = 683
07-23 16:40:58.369: DEBUG/Frank Liu(590): after block thread
07-23 16:40:58.369: DEBUG/Frank Liu(590): enter FDInfo-represent
07-23 16:40:58.379: DEBUG/Frank Liu(590): new jsonresp successfully
07-23 16:40:58.379: DEBUG/Frank Liu(590): begin put jsonresp
07-23 16:40:58.389: DEBUG/Frank Liu(590): end put jsonresp
07-23 16:40:58.409: DEBUG/Frank Liu(590): exit FDInfo-represent
07-23 16:40:58.409: DEBUG/Frank Liu(590): exit FDInfo-handle
```

Comment: To format code etc, select it and use Ctrl-K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would suggest is finding out what app that is.  I assume you are printing the log with the pids (though it is really hard because your log paste is all being wrapped); if so use "ps" to find out who pid 590.  Hopefully that is some third party app that you can just uninstall.

Comment: This looks to be com.fd.httpd.  I think this is an HTC Sync process, which needs to be running to allow me to access the device. Does this mean I can ignore this and my bug is elsewhere?

Comment: Probably.  Do you have any reason to think it is causing your problem?

Comment: I have got what looks like a memory leak, so this made me very suspicious.  However, if this was causing the problem my app would fall over no matter what I did.  This isn't happening, so I reckon you're right and the problem's elsewhere.  Ta for your help.